# Authenticating LDAP user and checking if they belong to a group

Tags: java, ldap

With the following code, I can bind/authenticate the user `testu` with password `testp` with my local LDAP server. In my DIT, this user also belongs to a group, say `Administrators`. How can I get the name of the group he belongs to or vice versa check if that user belongs to that group?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory" );
    properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:10389");

    // set properties for authentication
    properties.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=testu,ou=users,ou=system");
    properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "testp");

    try {
        InitialLdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(properties, null);          
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In my LDAP browser, in the Tree structure, I have the user `testu`

```
cn=testu,ou=users,ou=system
```

while the `Administrators` group is under

```
cn=Administrators,ou=groups,ou=system
```

Now I don't even think I've gotten the user in that group, but assuming I did how would you look for it? I'm basically asking how do I do a search query through LDAP relative to the user authenticated.

Given the following group:

```
cn=operations,ou=groups,ou=system
objectClass:groupOfNames (structural)
objectClass:top (abstract)
cn:operations
member:cn=soto,ou=users,ou=system
member:cn=testu,ou=users,ou=system
```

And this user:

```
cn=testu,ou=users,ou=system
objectClass:organizationalPerson (structural)
objectClass:person (structural)
objectClass:top (abstract)
cn:testu
sn:some name
userPassword:SHA hashed password    [testp]
```

How would I get the group from this user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you performed a bind, then you know the DN of the user and you could do a search request like:

Base Search DN: ou=system

```
(member=cn=testu,ou=users,ou=system)
```

This would, if you have permission, return all the groups the user is a DIRECT member.
It would not include any nested group memberships.

Comment: How do I check that permission? It might be different from LDAP server to LDAP server. I'm using Apache Directory Studio and I can browse pretty much everything.

Comment: Also what do you mean by DIRECT member? Because with scope `subtree` the query you posted didn't return anything.

Comment: A "DIRECT" member is a normal member of a group vs a Member which is another group. Some LDAP implementations can have a group as a member of another group. I would assume, the user you are using does not have the proper permissions or you are looking for groups in all the wrong places.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know LDAP does not attach any group information about the user currently logged in to the context. You can only indirectly find out about his/her powers by what actions work and what not - sure you do not plan to to it that way.

When if comes to checking if a user is in a certain group, or in general to send any query that should not view the world from the limited viewpoint of some user just logged in (or not logged in), I create a separate user on the ldap (the "application connection" user for that application) and then submit the query by connecting to that user. (This is in analogy to most SQL Servers where you have a DB Admin account that can do everything, but if you have an application you do not connect to the DB with the Admin account, but create a special user for that application that can only read and write the databases/tables it need to).

That is most probably a solution you have thought of yourself already, so the actual "answer" part of this post is that to my knowledge there is no other way.

Comment: I was hoping I could avoid putting the system admin user information in my application.

Comment: Yes, that is why I mean to create a separate "application admin" with powers limited to the ones needed by the application. It seems my answer has not been clear on that, should I try to make it more understandable?

Comment: Sure, please do. I haven't really gotten into the full structure of ldap directory schemas.

Comment: OK, give me a day. If no other points are brought, I'll give you the answer, because it would work. This whole LDAP world for authentication/authorization is new to me (and I don't like it).

Comment: I hope someone else comes in with a better answer in the meantime so I can learn something, too. Oh, and one really needs to get used to the LDAP way of things ...

Comment: Your answer just seems to be avoiding the issue. You can search LDAP for the groups he is a member of, or if your LDAP server maintains a `memberOF` attribute you can just query that. -1

Comment: As far as I understood the question was not about how to get at the group attributes, but how to solve permissions problems if the user is not allowed to read the groups he might or might not belongs to (e.g. if one needs to be in the `Administator` group to view by `memberOF` attributes of that group). (Ah, I see that part of the discussion has been gone together with a retracted answer.)

Comment: @ClemensKlein-Robbenhaar There is nothing in the question about 'permissions problems if the user is not allowed to read the groups ...' There is just a question as to how to read them: ' I'm basically asking how do I do a search query through LDAP relative to the user authenticated.'